# Android: FCM data insertion to db while app is offline

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to insert a FCM notification with getData() payload into sqlite db of the app. While the app does so while running, how can i do it offline?

I have tried it using WorkManager and also with ContextCompat.startForegroundService.But am not succesful.

An insight into this problem would be of help.

Here's what I am doing:

```
private void scheduleWorkManagerTask(PushNotification pushNotification){
        Data pushNotificationData = new Data.Builder()
                .putInt("id", pushNotification.getId())
                .putString("title", pushNotification.getTitle())
                .putString("body", pushNotification.getBody())
                .putString("image", pushNotification.getImageUrl())
                .putString("timestamp", pushNotification.getTimestamp())
                .putString("date", pushNotification.getDate())
                .build();

        OneTimeWorkRequest workRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
                .setInputData(pushNotificationData)
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).beginWith(workRequest).enqueue();
    }
```

Comment: You can do it on FirebaseMessagingService class file. It allows saving a data message in the database when it is received even offline.

Comment: Definitely I have the FirebaseMessagingService class implemented, thus I am getting the fcm notification with and without datapayload while the app runs but the data wont insert to the db while the app is not running actively. Thanks for reaching outl.

Comment: I achieved it by below code:
if (fcmReceived.data.isNotEmpty()) {
            val jsonString = fcmReceived.data // this is the JSON string, you can assign each value to a separate val and save it into room db.

}

Comment: Tried this way "   if (!remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty()){
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String jsonData = gson.toJson(data);
            Log.d(TAG, "Remote Data"+ jsonData);
            // Rest of the code
        }
" but to no avail.